# R: Grouping in a hierarchy

Tags: r, grouping, hierarchy

I'm working on a dataset with a with grouping-system with six digits. The first two digits denote grouping on the top-level, the next two denote different sub-groups, and the last two digits denote specific type within the sub-group. I want to group the data to the top level in the hierarchy (two first digits only), and count unique names in each group.

An example for the GroupID 010203:

- 01 denotes BMW
- 02 denotes 3-series
- 03 denotes 320i (the exact model)

All I care about in this example is how many of each brand there is.

Toy dataset and wanted output:

```
df <- data.table(Quarter = c('Q4', 'Q4', 'Q4', 'Q4', 'Q3'),
                 GroupID = c(010203, 150503, 010101, 150609, 010000),
                 Name = c('AAAA', 'AAAA', 'BBBB', 'BBBB', 'CCCC'))
```

Output:

```
Quarter     Group     Counts
Q3          01        1
Q4          01        2
Q4          15        2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `data.table` we could do:

```
library(data.table)

dt[, Group := substr(GroupID, 1, 2)][
   , Counts := .N, by = list(Group, Quarter)][
   , head(.SD, 1), by = .(Quarter, Group, Counts)][
   , .(Quarter, Group, Counts)]
```

Returns:

> ```
>    Quarter Group Counts
> 1:      Q4    01      2
> 2:      Q4    15      2
> 3:      Q3    01      1
> ```

With `dplyr` and `stringr` we could do something like:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Group = str_sub(GroupID, 1, 2)) %>% 
  group_by(Group, Quarter) %>% 
  summarise(Counts = n()) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Returns:

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 3
>   Group Quarter Counts
>   <chr> <fct>    <int>
> 1 01    Q3           1
> 2 01    Q4           2
> 3 15    Q4           2
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using `data.table`, you can do:

```
df[, Group := substr(GroupID,1,2)]
df <- df[,Counts := .N, .(Group,Quarter)][,.(Group, Quarter, Counts)]
df <- unique(df)
print(df)

   Group Quarter Counts
1:    10      Q4      2
2:    15      Q4      2
3:    10      Q3      1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my simple solution with `plyr` and `base R`, it is lightening fast.

```
library(plyr)
df$breakid <- as.character((substr(df$GroupID, start =0 , stop = 2)))
d <- plyr::count(df, c("Quarter", "breakid"))
```

**Result**

```
 Quarter breakid freq
      Q3      01    1
      Q4      01    2
      Q4      15    2
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, using `tapply` (and `data.table` indexing):

```
df$Brand <- substr(df$GroupID, 1, 2)
tapply(df$Brand, df[, .(Quarter, Brand)], length)
```

(If you don't care about the output being a matrix).